# Set JSON field to undefined if no user input in React - instead of an empty JSON object like "customer": { }

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

I have a JSON variable data that has a customer field with 6 properties:

```
const submit = async (values) => {

          const data = {
              customer: {
                firstname: values.firstname,
                lastname: values.lastname
                ...
              },
              ...
              ...
```

And a form in which user inputs are submitted to the JSON variable:

```
<Field name="firstname" component={InputField} type="text" />
<Field name="lastname" component={InputField} type="text" />
```

These fields are not required but the empty customer object still gets sent to my API as "customer": { } 
How can I get rid of it? I know if I set the customer object to undefined, it will be ignored from the whole JSON, but can't seem to figure out where I should set it so that it does not look bad. 

I guess it is something like this?

```
data.keys(customer).length > 1 ? customer : undefined
```

**Q:** is there any way to check inside the const variable, that values contain customer data, and if not, it defaults to undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data.customer = Object.keys(data.customer).length ? data.customer : undefined
```

Comment: the customer field actually has 6 properties, isn't the length() check better then?

Comment: So, every property of customer is optional?

Comment: yes every property of customer is optional

Comment: I edited the answer. I think in your case length is a way to go

Comment: actually this does not work, because the customer object lenght is always 6, but the properties inside are undefined

Answer (score 0):

By using delete keyword you can delete the customer property if it is empty, now your data will have all the properties without the customer property

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}

if('customer' in data)
{
    if(isEmpty(data.customer))
    delete data.customer;
}
```

Comment: I edited my code in the question, does this still hold true? adding that code to the class feels a bit too much.

Comment: In that case you can simply use if(values.firstname && values.lastname)   then do the const data={....}

Comment: Q: is there any way to check inside the const variable, that values contain customer data, and if not, it defaults to undefined?

For this question, using the if statement before assigning the customer attribute to data is the best way

Answer (score 0):

let name = {   d: 'test', };

let data = {   name: name.d ? name.d : undefined,   email: name.email ? name.email : undefined, };

1. List item

```js
let name = {
  d: 'test',
};

let data = {
  name: name.d ? name.d : undefined,
  email: name.email ? name.email : undefined,
};

console.log('data===>', data);
```

console.log('data===>', data);